# Gstreamer understanding

Tags: python, c, gstreamer

Okey guys I thought that after few days with gstreamer I understand it I wrote some pipelines with would logically work but I have headache when it comes to saving a stream to file.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rstp://ip/url ! decodebin ! textoverlay text="Work you damn thing " ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=some_video.mp4
```

Okey this is my logic:

```
 1. rtspsrc - has one pad and it's src it outputs x/rtps
 2. decodebin - is a bin (bunch of elements) it has ghost pads and one of those
    sink pads accept x/rtps then on source pad it generates raw video
 4. x264enc - accepts raw video on sink pad and encodes it to a h264 raw
    video
 5. h264parse - accepts raw h264 on sink and it parse it to h264 video
 6. mp4mux - muxing it
 7. filesink - it sinks it to a file
```

Everything is fine but after I finish recording it and when I try to play it I got this error:

> This file contain no playable stream

If there are some experianced users of gstreamer out there I would like to ask them where is the leak in my logic and what is cause of this error ?

Comment: I find it always useful to divide the pipeline and inject an autosink (autovideosink) and if needed a decodebin step by step to see where the desired output goes lost. The -vvvvv flag provides also a lot of useful info. Try to put an autovideosink directly after textoverlay and further a decodebin ! autovideosink combination if that is fine. See whether the video behind the mp4mux is still fine.

Comment: I got it I needed -e flag before rtpssrc tho I don't know what that flag does

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to send an EOS event to the pipeline, then wait for the EOS message on the bus of the pipeline, and only then shut down the pipeline (changing state from PLAYING to READY or NULL).

If you use gst-launch-1.0, use the -e parameter. When you then hit ctrl+c it will do exactly that before shutting down everything.

This is needed as in the end mp4mux needs to finalize the file and write information about the complete stream in the file. Otherwise the file is not a valid MP4 file.

Comment: Is it because the moov atom is being written at the end of the file only after mp4mux received an EOS?

Comment: Thx for explanation. If I may ask one more question why does gstreamer creates  file with 24 hour duration when Iam trying to mux audio(filesrc) and video(rtspsrc) with flvmux ?